# Facebook Canvas App in WebView not working on Android (in native facebook app)

Tags: android, facebook, android-canvas

I have developed a Facebook canvas app, which works fine on the Web, and iOS (mobile web view) however on Android, specifically a Galaxy S4, the app won't load and the Facebook app delivers a message saying:

```
"[AppName] is incompatible with your device. Please visit the App Centre to find apps for this device."
```

The mobile web URL is set and it works fine on iOS devices HTTPS certificate is correct and set properly.

Facebook's own documentation states that it will open the app in a web view if the mobile URL is set. However, I'm not even getting a request to my server from the phone.

Any ideas??

Comment: We are currentky encountering the same issues. I tried to load a simple facebook canvas application displaying a simple HTML, and it ended up displaying it after loading about 20 seconds. Seems that there's something going wrong with displaying canvas pages inside the facebook app on android.

Comment: Hi! anyone found the solution for this? i have the same problem and i dont know what to do. Only in android cellphones.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem with the following steps:

1. Enter the facebook delevopers center and choose the app .
2. On the Settings tab , include the Facebook canvas platform and website (it's important to include both platforms and fill all fields).
3. In the App Details tab, go to the App center platforms listed and turn on the items "App on Facebook" and "Website - Mobile".
4. In the Status & Review tab, start a submission.
5. Wait for the approval of the facebook team.
6. After this your application will run on Android, iOS and Web.